# How to secure data transmission over a non-secure Wi-Fi

Tags: security, ieee-802.11

I connect to a organization's non-secure Wi-Fi provided to guests.
it is said that my data transmissions are not private and could be intercepted by others.

What can I do to secure my data transmission, for example, for web browsing, email, on Ubuntu 14.04 (my laptop) and Android 4.4.2 (my phone)?

Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a secure tunnel relying on encription at least to somewhere outside the WIFI zone. You can use ssh port forwarding or VPN.

I use Debian in my notebook and I use the tool openvpn to set a VPN tunnel to encrypt my notebook's entire traffic until it reaches the VPN server. With VPN you can choose if you route all or individual ports to the VPN server and you can use ssh forwading to a remote server on specific ports too, such as 80 and 443.

Sry, dont know about VPN apps on android yet.